# Overlapping Chinese characters using xeLatex kaiu TrueType Font - Windows

Tags: languages, xecjk

I am quite new to using xeCJK and xelatex in general, so please bear with me.

I tried the following code:

> Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} % for \rotatebox

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\newfontlanguage{Chinese}{CHN}
\setCJKmainfont{kaiu.ttf}
\setCJKfamilyfont{songvert}     [Script=CJK,Language=Chinese, Vertical=RotatedGlyphs]{kaiu.ttf}

\newcommand*\CJKmovesymbol[1]{\raise0.35em\hbox{#1}}
\newcommand*\CJKmove{\punctstyle{plain}% do not modify the spacing between punctuations
\let\CJKsymbol\CJKmovesymbol
\let\CJKpunctsymbol\CJKsymbol}


\begin{document}

屈原《离骚》曰：
\begin{center}
\rotatebox{-90}{
\begin{minipage}{5em}
\CJKfamily{songvert}\CJKmove
    你是\\
    好
\end{minipage}}
\end{center}

这裡羲和便等于一名馬车夫，因为
他是御日的，诗人生怕太阳赶快落了，就叫羲和慢一点走。　不过话经我
一翻译，显得淘气一点，原文只是一个高贵的身分，另外不表现着什么个性了。

\end{document}
```

> And got the following results:

[image]

As you can see, the 「好」 is fine, but that first line is messed up (overlapping).
This only happened when I used kaiu.ttf, if I were to change it to SimSun, it would be fine.

I need to use kaiu.ttf (標楷體), not SimSun

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: It looks that it is a commercial font from the [DFKai-SB family](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1584), but I've found and installed some version from [2shared.com](http://www.2shared.com/complete/EYdNeD4q/kaiu.html) and the result looks fine (XeLaTeX, TeXLive 2013).

Comment: @Malipivo I downloaded and installed the kaiu.ttf from that link you shared, got the same results!

Maybe its an OS issue? I'm using Windows 8 service pack 1

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your situation, yet, I've used MS Windows XP SPv2 and Lubuntu 13.10. Have you tried to upgrade the TeXLive? Or are you using the MikTeX distribution?

Comment: I use TexMaker 4.2 and MikTex 2.9, using XeLatex + View PDF build option, again, on Windows 8 service pack 1

Comment: I have been playing around and found that the problem can be solved by just merely adding spaces.
I.E.: 你\quad 是
the font probably doesnt support vertical typesetting spacing :(

Comment: It seems that the font has wrong metric information. We don't actually have a good solution. I guess you can use another font.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is not reproducible